# Haskell: Why is the type inferred by GHC for main method not quite complete?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, ghci

For example, take the code written by Don Stewart in reply to some Stack Overflow question:

```
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.HashTable as H
import System.Environment

main = do
  [size] <- fmap (fmap read) getArgs
  m <- H.new (==) H.hashInt
  forM_ [1..size] $ \n -> H.insert m n n
  v <- H.lookup m 100
  print v
```

Load it in GHCi.

```
:t getArgs ---> getArgs :: IO [String]
:t main    ---> main :: IO ()
```

Why doesn't the type signature of main reflect the fact that `getArgs :: IO [String]` is being called?

When you run the binary you can give an argument.
`<prog> 145` returns `Just 100`
But in GHCi, you cannot: `main 145` gives error. How do you run this program in GHCi and give an argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `main` is that of its final expression; `print` produces `IO ()`, so that's the type of `main`.  Intermediate types are not relevant, as `(>>=)` doesn't propagate anything other than the monad.

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

`a` doesn't appear in the result type (`m b`).

As for running your program in GHCi, take a look at the `:main` command.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that *do* is syntactic sugar for >>= and its signature is *(>>=) :: (Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b*. However, even when monadic operations are used, is it not possible for the compiler to make use of the fact that getArgs which has a type signature of *getArgs :: IO [String]* is being used in the computation? And provide a more meaningful type signature? Or is this is not possible at all?

Comment: Not in Haskell.. and it's not clear to me what value there would be in doing so beyond what's already there (`IO`). It's information that is helpful to the compiler, but not otherwise. Unless what you're really thinking about is splitting `IO` up, which is a perennial discussion topic that comes down to it being a logistical nightmare.

Comment: If this bothers you then just put all your code in a `mainX :: [String] -> IO ()` function and have `main = getArgs >>= mainX`

Answer (score 4):

You want to `:set` the value of args. For example:

```
Prelude> import System.Environment
Prelude System.Environment> getArgs
[]
Prelude System.Environment> :set args ["foo","bar"]
Prelude System.Envrionment> getArgs
["foo","bar"]
```

As for the type signature issue, the type of main here is determined by `print v`. Everything else before it is ignored via the `>>` operator.